# Javascript, map returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dictionary

So I have 24 "person" objects, which I created using "names" array, so that "dude" names are repeating;
Next I made a function that compares some random numbers to object id-s, and if they are equal,then I am trying to make new array of person names that go with that id.

(I'm sorry if this sounds too complicated, but I really don't understand why my **map method** doesn't work.)

Here 2 versions of my code. **The first one works, and does what I want.**

```js
var names = ["jim", "jack", "aaron", "hugh", "jeff", "cameron", "allen", "charlie"];
var len = 3,
  arr1 = [],
  counter = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  names.forEach(name => {
    arr1.push({
      id: counter,
      dude: name
    });
    counter++;
  });
}

console.log(arr1);

function checkName(nums) {
  var namesarr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    nums.forEach(function(num) {
      if (num === arr1[i].id) {
        namesarr.push(arr1[i].dude);
      }
    });
  }
  return (namesarr);
};

console.log(checkName([1, 3, 6]));
```

But in second version, **my map function returns undefined,** and I really don't understand why?!

```js
var names = ["jim", "jack", "aaron", "hugh", "jeff", "cameron", "allen", "charlie"];
var len = 3,
  arr1 = [],
  counter = 1;


for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  names.forEach(name => {
    arr1.push({
      id: counter,
      dude: name
    });
    counter++;
  });
}

console.log(arr1);

function checkName(nums) {
  var namesarr;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    namesarr = nums.map(function(num) {
      if (num === arr1[i].id) {
        return arr1[i].dude;
      }
    });
  }
  return (namesarr);
};
console.log(checkName([1, 3, 6]));
```

Comment: Your `map` function always returns something. If you don’t do it in an explicit `return` statement, the return value is `undefined`. In other words: you can’t use `map` to make an array with a different length[\*](https://stackoverflow.com/# "unless the original array is sparse").

Comment: `namesarr.filter(a => a != null)` would get rid of the undefined but in general not returning in a map looks iffy. Use the filter before the map to remove the unwanted values.

Comment: try `.map(your map code).filter(code to filter out undefined)` or the other way around :p

Comment: that does seem a bit over complicated compared to just `console.log( [1, 3, 6].map(i => names[i - 1]) );`

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the `namesarr` variable on each iteration of the loop. I think you meant to add to it on each pass, rather than overwrite it. To do that, you can use the array `.concat` method.

Then, finally, make sure to filter all the `undefined` values from the result before you return it.

```js
var names = ["jim", "jack", "aaron", "hugh", "jeff", "cameron", "allen", "charlie"];
var len = 3,
  arr1 = [],
  counter = 1;


for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  names.forEach(name => {
    arr1.push({
      id: counter,
      dude: name
    });
    counter++;
  });
}

console.log(arr1);

function checkName(nums) {
    var namesarr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        namesarr = namesarr.concat(nums.map(function(num) {
            if(num === arr1[i].id) {
                return arr1[i].dude;
            }
        }));
    }
    return (namesarr.filter(Boolean));
};
console.log(checkName([1,3,6]));
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of `map()` is an array of all the returned values. If a function doesn't execute a `return` statement, it's equivalent to ending with `return undefined`.

In your second version, whenever the `if` condition fails, you don't execute `return arr1[i].dude;`, so it's returning `undefined` by default. It's as if you'd written:

```
namesarr = nums.map(function(num) {
  if (num === arr1[i].id) {
    return arr1[i].dude;
  } else {
    return undefined;
  }
});
```

The other difference between your two versions of the code is that the second version reassigns `namesarr` each time through the `for` loop. So you're just printing the result of the last iteration.

The first version assigns it once before the loop, and adds to it only when the `if` condition succeeds, so you get the elements from all iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Your `map` function doesn't return something for all the items in the array (because of the `if`) so some values in the result array will be `undefined`.

Plus, your `map` is inside a loop that loops over `arr1`, so for each iteration of that loop, the array `namesarr` get overridden. So the `map` will be as if it was applied only for the last element in `arr1`, thus if `nums` contain `N` elements then `namesarr` will have at least `N - 1` `undefined` values in it (`N - 1` if the last object of `arr1` matches `nums`, `N` if not).

The problem is better solved using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead of `map`:

```
function checkName(nums) {
    return arr1.reduce(function(namesarr, obj) {     // for each object obj in the array arr1
        if(nums.indexOf(obj.id) !== -1) {            // if the object's id is in the array nums
            namesarr.push(obj.dude);                 // then add the object's dude to the array namesarr
        }
        return namesarr;
    }, []);                                          // the empty array to initialize namesarr
}
```