# How to I prevent the following map function from returning undefined objects?

Tags: javascript

I have a function loops through an array, rearranges its objects, and returns the result (excluding the current object):

```
// buildings = [{ objectId: '1', objectId: '2', objectId: '3' }]
// currentBuilding = { objectId: '1' }
const result buildings.map(building => {
  if (building.objectId === this.currentBuilding.objectId) {
    return
  }
  return {
    newField: building.objectId,
  }
})
return result
```

I want it to return:

This function will return:

```
[{ newField: '2', newField: '3' }]
```

However, now I'm getting:

```
[{ undefined, newField: '2', newField: '3' }]
```

Why is this and how to fix it?

Comment: You can't. `map` always returns an array of all the results, and `return;` is the same as `return undefined;`.

Comment: Either use `reduce` so you can decide whether to add to the result, or use `filter` to remove the undefined elements from the result.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47584705/javascript-map-returns-undefined/47584789#47584789 for a similar problem.

Comment: There is no way the input and result contain an object with the same properties, so please update your question with correct input and result.

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing. `buildings` in your code looks like an array with one element, which is an object with multiple duplicate keys. Are you sure that's right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, but you can filter out the offending item:

```
const result buildings.filter(b => b.objectId !== this.currentBuilding.objectId)
                      .map(b => ({newField: b.objectId});
```